# Passing of variables between two functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameter-passing

Is there any way to pass variables between two functions in Python without having to use another function, like main() ?

```
def fun1 (arg1:int) -> None: 
    random1 =  10 * arg1
    return(random1)

def fun2 (bounds:tuple) -> int: 

    random2 = fun1 (random1)

    if random2 > bounds [1] or random2 > bounds [2]: 
        return (random2)

    else: 
        pass
```

Basically I'm trying to pass the variable random from fun1 to fun2. But Eclipse keeps saying: "Undefined variable: random".

Any ideas?

Comment: What value do you want to pass *to* `fun1()`? That `random` value is not defined.

Comment: Note: you can completely drop the `else: pass` lines.

Comment: your function definition ```def fun1 (arg1:int) -> None:``` does not look like valid python, does it?

Comment: @dorvak: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside the functions (and before the function definitions), you would declare an instance of `random` by assigning something to it. (E.g.: `random = none`) Then, in each of the functions in which you wish to use it, it will be available for use. If necessary, you may even want to include the line

```
global random
```

in each of the functions where it's used in order to make it clear that you're using a global variable. (Of course, use of global variables is, by its very nature, not easily maintainable and goes against both object oriented and procedural programming practices.)

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. But just out of curiosity, it there any better way to pass value of one variable to another function?

Comment: @tradt what's "better" in this context? It's indeed a global variable if it's available without being passed around.

Comment: @tradt: Function arguments in Python are passed by object reference, so unless a variable that is passed in is a mutable object, any changes made to that argument by the callee will not be seen by the caller. So if you're assigning strings, numbers or other immutable objects to that variable, a global variable is your only option for changing a variable in one function that another function will use. (BTW, I've added an example for defining an instance of the global variable in my answer.)

Comment: @ RobH: Thanks, I think I got it now. Still hard to adjust to Python after working mostly with functional programming languages.

Comment: @ Simeon Visser: Better in the sense that there might be a way to pass the value of fun1 to fun2 without using globals. But I guess there isn't; if fun1 isn't returning any value and is just used to define a a variable.

Comment: @tradt: Looking at your code a bit more closely, since your first function is assigning to the global variable, it need not return a value at all. In your second function, the assignment to `random2` at the call to the first function can be removed, and all instances of `random2` can be replaced by `random1`. Or, you can go the other way and have the first function return the result of the calculation directly and replace all instances of `random2` in the second function with `random1`. In the latter case, the first function doesn't even know or care about the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`random` is not defined in `fun2` when it's used for the first time:

```
def fun2 (bounds:tuple) -> int: 

    random = fun1 (random) # what value should be passed to fun1 here?
```

Comment: I'm trying to use fun1 to store the value of the variable "random". So that its possible to use this value in another function (fun2) later, if needed. Is there any way to store a value of a variable globally?